# Creating an ASP.Net MVC link in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my jQuery function I have this line to create an MVC URL:

```
$('#response').append("<a href=\'\@Url.Action(\"Details\",\"Member\")\'>my link</a>")
```

My understanding is that I need to escape the `@` character in order to get the link working, but it won't let me.  Is there another way to render the link I'm trying to create?

Comment: This will not work because `Url.Action` is C# code. Try `$('#response').append('<a href="/Details/Member">my link</a>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the Razor code is output on the server, long before the JS runs, so you don't need to escape anything. This should work for you, so long as the value `@Url.Action` provides is valid and you execute this where the Razor syntax will be interpreted (ie. not in an external .js file):

```
$('#response').append('<a href="@Url.Action("Details","Member")">my link</a>');
```